# Historical figures word search with a twist

Tags: history, word-search

You can take every path you like from the drawn paths, but you cannot repeat letters in the same word (person's name).

There are at least 23 historical figures on the board.

[image: wordsearch]

Here is also a text version of the grid:

```
F---E---U---E---N---R---T  
|\ /|\ /|\ /|\ /|\ /|\ /|  
| R-+-C-+-D-+-A-+-E-+-I |  
|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|  
O-+-C-+-I-+-C-+-N-+-T-+-I  
|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|  
| H-+-E-+-M-+-E-+-F-+-A |  
|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|  
E-+-L-+-A-+-K-+-N-+-R-+-C  
|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|  
| G-+-N-+-D-+-S-+-A-+-P |  
|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|  
L-+-S-+-T-+-H-+-O-+-B-+-O  
|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|  
| O-+-E-+-A-+-G-+-G-+-L |  
|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|  
C-+-N-+-S-+-L-+-S-+-A-+-O  
|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|\|/|  
| R-+-T-+-I-+-E-+-D-+-A |  
|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|/ \|  
F---A---N---L---I---M---S
```

PS. There are no unused letters on the board.

Hint:

> 5 people are still missing from all the answers. 4 are writers and 1 is a navigator. The 5 words are respectively of lengths: 5, 6, 7, 7, 8.

Comment: No Cleopatra? :P

Comment: No Cleopatra this time. :)

Comment: I can get Gama, Cartier, He

Comment: Are we allowed Aragon (as in Catherine of)

Comment: Helena (2,4)(1,5)(3,5)(4,4)(4,6)(5,5), i.e. female equivalent naming protocol as in 'Caeser'?

Comment: Gama, I have missed. Cartier is the navigator.

Comment: `Dickens` can be the 7 letter writer at (6,2).

Comment: @Takeshi, he is.

Comment: "You cannot repeat letters in the same word" ― do you mean the same letter as in "twice an E", or the same letter as in "twice the same node with an E in it"? Or said differently, if there were a historical figure of that name, would "Feuen" (from the first line) be valid?

Comment: @celtschk, I mean the same node. So if Feuen was a name of a historical figure, it would be valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found:

> [image: completedwordsearch]
>  in 18, so added 5 more.
> RED:5
> Freud
> Franco
> Anne Frank
> Gogh
> Adams
>
> GREEN:3
> Bonaparte
> Michelangelo
> Galilei
>
> BLUE:4
> Stalin
> Edison
> Dean (James)
> Carter (Howard)
>
> PURPLE:2
> Dante
> Caesar
>
> YELLOW:4
> Socrates
> Nefertiti
> Cicero
> Polo
>
> Also:5
> Kant
> Dali
> Madison
> Nelson
> Mao (Chinese put surname first)
>
> Cartier, Helena, Dickens, Tesla, Stendhal, Menes, Frost, Manet

Are we done?

Comment: 5 are still missing. :)

Comment: could you tell me name lengths? :)

Comment: 5, 6, 7, 7 and 8.

Comment: Jacques Cartier is a Navigator with length 7, but it feels like it would be cheating, since it uses the same letters as Carter (plus 1)...

Comment: That is the one. @Chelsea

Answer (score 9):

I've found up to 27 possibilities so far,
Please let me know if any don't qualify for obvious reasons :)
Also I am done for at least a couple hours, because I've been shirking work for too long looking at this.

> 1. Franco - bottom left
> <s>Satan - centre left low</s> -thought myth may count as history
> 2. Dante - centre left
> 3. Stalin - bottom centre left
> <s>Cena - centre high</s> -this one was certainly a long shot
> 4. Manet - centre left
> 5. Kant - centre
> Dante again - upper centre right
> <s>Brago - centre right</s> -oops, was thinking Bragi, Norse God and namesake of a couple Skalds...
> 6. Galilei - bottom centre
> 7. Nelson - centre left
> 8. Freud - top left
> 9. Socrates - bottom left
> 10. Midas - bottom right, may have myth problem
> 11. Barnes - centre right
> 12. Michelangelo- left edge to upper centre
> <s>Pate- upper right</s> obscure
> <s>Boggs- centre right low</s> obscure/not historical enough
> 13. Caesar- upper centre right
> <s>Cane- upper centre</s>obscure
> 14. Mao- bottom right -Thanks @Kiwi
> 15. Rocci- top left
> 16. Anne Frank - top centre to centre right
> <s>Alba/D'Alba - low right</s> obscure
> 17. Bonaparte- upper centre right -Thanks @Jon Mark Perry
>  <s>Senna- upper centre right</s>  modern
> <s>Nadal- low centre left</s> presupposing strike-through for modernity
> 18. Hogg- low centre right
>  <s>Stiles- bottom centre</s> obscure
> 19. Nefertiti- Top right
> 20. Adams- Bottom right -Thanks @David Starkey
> 21. Dali-Low centre
> 22. Saint Arc - bottom centre to bottom left
> 23. Stetson - low left
> 24. El Cid - upper left
> 25. Asohka - centre
> 26. Helen - left
> 27. Cicero - top left
> 27.5. Dame... someone, middle left, possibly Cleo. It doesn't look entirely like an accident, but I've also not got a good name.

Several are also present in @Kruga's excellent answer, but given it's breadth and good formatting, I don't feel comfortable stealing them.

Comment: Satan is not a real historical figure, Cena is a very recent one and I don't know if he counts. Also, repetitions do not count - if you find the same person twice, they are counted only once. Brago - couldn't find information on a real historical figure with this name.

Comment: Great. But Dante could only be counted once :). Also, the 20th person is missing their first name - it is on the grid. :) Who are 14, 15, 17 and 21? If we don't count them, you have 6 extras.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Robert Pate attacked Queen Victoria, probably not well known outside England, Wade Boggs is a famous former baseball player, and Governor Boggs of Missouri had a run-in with the Mormans Facino Cane was a renaissance Italian that Balzac wrote a book about, and Macrino d'Alba was a guy I learned about in Art History class I think? Wikipedia apparently has a small article on him, so I'm not entirely nuts. Guess none of those count though.

Comment: Well, they could be counted as extras. So you have 10 extras, 10 finds, at least 12 more to go. if you happen to find more extras. :)

Comment: 18 can be perceived as a bit too modern, 16 is still missing their first name, 20? For 20 I found some recent people as well, but perhaps you had something else in mind? And 19 is an extra, as well. :)

Comment: PS. There are no unused letters on the board. :)

Comment: Adams (bottom right) for the [2nd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Adams) / [6th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Quincy_Adams) US President or the [founding father / beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Adams).

Answer (score 8):

Found <s>25</s> a bunch.

> [Freud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmund_Freud) (1,1)
>  [Gogh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh) (10,8)
>  [Caesar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Caesar) (7,3)
>  [Stalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Stalin) (5,9)
>  [Edison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Edison) (8,10)
>  [Madison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Madison) (11,11)
>  [Galilei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei) (8,8)
>  [Kant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant) (7,5)
>  [Adams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Adams) (11,9)
>  [Socrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socrates) (3,7)
>  [Cicero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicero) (3,3)
>  [Michelangelo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelangelo) (6,4)
>  [Tesla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikola_Tesla) (5,7)
>  [Dante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dante_Alighieri) (6,6)
>  [Bonaparte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon) (11,7)
>  [Nelson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horatio_Nelson,_1st_Viscount_Nelson) (4,6)
>  [Anne Frank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Frank) (8,2)
>  [Polo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Polo) (12,6)
>  [Mao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mao_Zedong) (11,11)
>  [Menes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menes) (6,4)
>  [Stendhal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stendhal) (3,7)
>  [Frost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Frost) (1,11)
>  [Cartier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Cartier) (13,5)
>  [Dickens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Dickens) (6,2) Found by Takeshi
>  [Nefertiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nefertiti) (9,3) Found by Sconibulus and Jon Mark Perry
>  [Fante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Fante) (1,11)
>  [Conan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Conan_Doyle) (1,9)
>  [Ellison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Ellison) (8,10)
>  [Sendak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Sendak) (3,7)
>  [Celan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Celan) (3,3)
>  [Crane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Crane) (1,9)

Confirmed wrong

> [Lama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalai_Lama) (12,8)

The coordinates is where the name starts, with (1,1) being the upper left F, (13,1) the upper right T, and (13,11) the lower right S.

Comment: I am not sure Lama should be counted - I haven't counted it, as it is not a real name, it is something like a title. And 16 of the names I have included in my count of 23. So you have only 7 left.

Comment: Gonna take a break for now. Can you confirm if these are right?

Comment: 17 of these I have included in the count. :) Of the 6 left - one is 9 letters long, one is 8 letters long, 2 are 7 letters long, 1 is 6 letters long and one is 5 letters long.

Comment: Just a thought: Since the names are surnames, shouldn't Nelson be [Horatio Nelson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horatio_Nelson,_1st_Viscount_Nelson)?

Comment: @SMSvonderTann you are right. Was actually the one I thought of when I found it, but I guess I forget when I was putting in the links.

Comment: Both you and Jon Mark Perry are still missing 2 writers - admitted, they are not as famous, so perhaps we could scrub them? :) The 2 writers are with 5 and 6 letters. And Frost I have missed. I am thinking - shall we call it done and I would give the accepted answer to Jon and to you I will give a bounty of 50 - because I like the presentation? :) Otherwise I am sure you can find even more. :)

Comment: If these are not right I'm giving up now. I used [this list](http://www.famousauthors.org/list) to find writers. Also found some non-historic or non-last name, which I'm gonna list here just in case. Ellis, Helen, Banks, Barnes, Khaled, Khalil, Michel, Niall, Stieg, and Neale.

Comment: The ones I included are not present in this list. One of them is in this one: http://www.victorianweb.org/victorian/authors/ and the other is in this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_authors_by_name:_B  But I guess they are not famous enough, so I will discard them :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found four that I can add on to @Sconibulus' answer

> 1. Pablo - Mid-right (Pablo Picasso, Spanish artist)  
> 2. Leo - Mid-left (Leo Tolstoy, Russian author)
>  
> 3. Mata - Slightly above center (Mata Hari, Dutch dancer) 
> 4. Mao - Bottom right (Mao Zedong, leader of the Chinese communist revolution)

Comment: Unless they are famous with their first names, I have usually used their last name or both. But these could be extra to the ones I have placed on the grid.

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize I needed both. Thanks for the clarification :)